# Tags property of Visual C# components

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

Where can I use **Tag** property of the component in visual c#?

Answer (score 0):

msdn article says

> "A common use for the Tag property is
>   to store data that is closely
>   associated with the control. For
>   example, if you have a control that
>   displays information about a customer,
>   you might store a DataSet that
>   contains the customer's order history
>   in that control's Tag property so the
>   data can be accessed quickly."

In past I have also used it to save such information or associated Ids and such.

Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx)